# Rotation issue in Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The x-value of the rotation keeps changing to -180 when the nav mesh agent (enemy) collides with the player, but i want it to stay at -90.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    public Transform player;
    public float chaseCooldownTime = 3f; // Adjust this as needed
    private bool canChase = true;
    private Quaternion targetRotation;

    void Update()
    {
        if (player && canChase)
        {
            // Set destination for NavMeshAgent
            agent.SetDestination(player.position);

            // Rotate towards player
            RotateTowardsPlayer();
        }
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        if (player != null && canChase)
        {
            // Apply rotation to the enemy without changing the pitch or roll
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation.eulerAngles.x -90, targetRotation.eulerAngles.y + 90, 0);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            canChase = false;
            Invoke("ResetChase", chaseCooldownTime);
        }
    }

    void ResetChase()
    {
        canChase = true;
    }

    void RotateTowardsPlayer()
    {
        // Calculate direction from enemy to player
        Vector3 directionToPlayer = player.position - transform.position;
        directionToPlayer.y = 0; // Ignore vertical component

        // Calculate rotation to face player
        targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(directionToPlayer);
    }
}
```

I tried many different ways to do it but couldn't figure it out. Help Pls!

Here are the image of what is happening;
[image: no description]

Comment: transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(targetRotation.eulerAngles.x -90, targetRotation.eulerAngles.y + 90, 0);  I also fear the picture means more to you as you know what it should look like.. we dont.. but you could just have it self level after.. and lerp it back to what should be more normal to make it level - on which ever axis is relefvant.

Comment: ok so what change should i make?

Comment: you need to change which axis is relevant, so if its flipping around y, then change y, if its flipping around x (probably pitch, im not an aviation nut so easy get them confused) then change x..  (which I already said)

Comment: On the image you have enemy car that lays on right side under 90 degrees angle to x-axis. Where is 180 degrees that you are talking about?